# lisf of table without citep

Tags: captions

I'm writing my thesis. I have several captions of tables like this:

```
\caption{Composição química média de folhosas, em percentagem ponderal (base seca) \citep{ferreira}.}
```

I use `citep` in caption. But I dont want this in my list of tables. It it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think it is. `\caption` has an optional parameter, with which you specify what you want in the list of tables.

The easiest way for you to do this (I'm making assumptions about the general layout of your captions) might be this:

```
\newcommand{\icaption}[2]{\caption[#1.]{#1 \citep{#2}.}}
```

and in your document:

```
\icaption{Composição química média de folhosas, em percentagem ponderal (base seca)}{ferreira}
```